# Is there a way to run multiple forms all acting independently in react and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```html
This is my formik code, it seems this is where the error is coming from....


import * as React from 'react';
import { FormikConfig, FormikErrors, FormikState, FormikTouched, FormikValues, FieldMetaProps, FieldHelperProps, FieldInputProps } from './types';
export declare function useFormik<Values extends FormikValues = FormikValues>({ validateOnChange, validateOnBlur, validateOnMount, isInitialValid, enableReinitialize, onSubmit, ...rest }: FormikConfig<Values>): {
    initialValues: Values;
    initialErrors: FormikErrors<unknown>;
    initialTouched: FormikTouched<unknown>;
    initialStatus: any;
    handleBlur: {
        (e: React.FocusEvent<any>): void;
        <T = any>(fieldOrEvent: T): T extends string ? (e: any) => void : void;
    };
    handleChange: {
        (e: React.ChangeEvent<any>): void;
        <T_1 = string | React.ChangeEvent<any>>(field: T_1): T_1 extends React.ChangeEvent<any> ? void : (e: string | React.ChangeEvent<any>) => void;
    };
    handleReset: (e: any) => void;
    handleSubmit: (e?: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> | undefined) => void;
    resetForm: (nextState?: Partial<FormikState<Values>> | undefined) => void;
    setErrors: (errors: FormikErrors<Values>) => void;
    setFormikState: (stateOrCb: FormikState<Values> | ((state: FormikState<Values>) => FormikState<Values>)) => void;
    setFieldTouched: (field: string, touched?: boolean, shouldValidate?: boolean | undefined) => Promise<FormikErrors<Values>> | Promise<void>;
    setFieldValue: (field: string, value: any, shouldValidate?: boolean | undefined) => Promise<FormikErrors<Values>> | Promise<void>;
    setFieldError: (field: string, value: string | undefined) => void;
    setStatus: (status: any) => void;
    setSubmitting: (isSubmitting: boolean) => void;
    setTouched: (touched: FormikTouched<Values>, shouldValidate?: boolean | undefined) => Promise<FormikErrors<Values>> | Promise<void>;
    setValues: (values: React.SetStateAction<Values>, shouldValidate?: boolean | undefined) => Promise<FormikErrors<Values>> | Promise<void>;
    submitForm: () => Promise<any>;
    validateForm: (values?: Values) => Promise<FormikErrors<Values>>;
    validateField: (name: string) => Promise<void> | Promise<string | undefined>;
    isValid: boolean;
    dirty: boolean;
    unregisterField: (name: string) => void;
    registerField: (name: string, { validate }: any) => void;
    getFieldProps: (nameOrOptions: any) => FieldInputProps<any>;
    getFieldMeta: (name: string) => FieldMetaProps<any>;
    getFieldHelpers: (name: string) => FieldHelperProps<any>;
    validateOnBlur: boolean;
    validateOnChange: boolean;
    validateOnMount: boolean;
    values: Values;
    errors: FormikErrors<Values>;
    touched: FormikTouched<Values>;
    isSubmitting: boolean;
    isValidating: boolean;
    status?: any;
    submitCount: number;
};
export declare function Formik<Values extends FormikValues = FormikValues, ExtraProps = {}>(props: FormikConfig<Values> & ExtraProps): JSX.Element;
/**
 * Transform Yup ValidationError to a more usable object
 */
export declare function yupToFormErrors<Values>(yupError: any): FormikErrors<Values>;
/**
 * Validate a yup schema.
 */
export declare function validateYupSchema<T extends FormikValues>(values: T, schema: any, sync?: boolean, context?: any): Promise<Partial<T>>;
/**
 * Recursively prepare values.
 */
export declare function prepareDataForValidation<T extends FormikValues>(values: T): FormikValues;
```

```html
This is my nodejs code....



const {
    models: { Withdraw, User },
    sequelize,
  } = require("../service/db/sequelize");
  
  const makeWithdraw = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { account, name,  amount, paymentmethod } = req.body;
    const { id } = req.payload.dataValues;
    try {
      const withdraw = await Withdraw.create({
        account: account,
        amount: amount,
        userId: id,

      });
  
      if (!withdraw)
        throw createHttpError.InternalServerError("Unable To Create Deposit");
  
      res.send({
        status: 200,
        withdraw: withdraw,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
  
  const getWithdraws = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const usersData = []
      const withdraw = await Withdraw.findAll();
      
      if (!withdraw) throw createHttpError.InternalServerError();
     
      withdraw.map(user => {
        const userDetail = {
          ...user.dataValues,
          createdAt: new Date(user.createdAt).toDateString()
        }
        usersData.push(userDetail)
  
      })
      res.send({
        status: 200,
        withdraw: usersData,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
  
  const getUserWithdraws = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.payload.dataValues;
    const usersData = []
    
    try {
      const user = await User.findByPk(id, { include: ["withdraws"] });
      
      if (!user) throw createHttpError.InternalServerError();
      const { withdraws } = user;
      
      const lastWithdraw = Number(withdraws[withdraws.length - 1].amount);
      const allWithdraws = [];
      let totalWithdraws = 0;
  
      await withdraws.map((withdraw) => {
         allWithdraws.push(Number(withdraw.amount));
         const userDetail = {
          ...withdraw.dataValues,
          createdAt: new Date(user.createdAt).toDateString()
        }
        usersData.push(userDetail)
      });
  
      totalWithdraws = allWithdraws.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  
      res.send({
        status: 200,
        userWithdraws:usersData,
        withdraws: allWithdraws,
        lastWithdraw:lastWithdraw,
        totalWithdraws:totalWithdraws
      });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
  
  const approveWithDraw = async(req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const {id}  = req.body;
    const withdraw = await Withdraw.update(
      {
          status:"Successful"
      },
      {
      where:{
        id:id
      }
    }
    
    );

  }
  module.exports = { makeWithdraw, getWithdraws, getUserWithdraws, approveWithDraw };
```

Good day stacoverflow. I am a newbiee to react and nodejs and i am trying to create multiple individual forms in a page that will act independently and pass data when filled. Everything seems to be working fine but when i try filling a form it just goes blank, i wonder what the issue is, i have tried my best but to no avail

```html
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import SpringModal from "../../components/Modal/Modal";
import { StyledWithdraw } from "./StyledWithdraw";
import Inputs from "../../components/inputs/Inputs";
import { Form, Formik } from "formik";
import Button from "../../components/Button/Button";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";


const initialValues = {
  paymentmethod: "",
  account: "",
  amount: "",
};
const Witdraw = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("user");
  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    console.log(values);
    try {
      axios
        .post(
          "http://localhost:8660/v1/auth/add/withdraw",
          {
            ...values,
          },
          {
            headers: {
              authorization: `${token}`,
            },
          }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            console.log(response);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  return (
    
      <div className=" container grid grid-cols-2 py-12 gap-6">
        
        <SpringModal imageUrl={card} details="Transfers">
          <div className="flex justify-center">
            <img src={card} alt="" className="pay_logo w-20 h-20 " />
          </div>
          <Formik>
            <Form>
              <div className="mt-4">
                <div className="">
                  <Inputs
                    label={"Full Name"}
                    type={"text"}
                    name={"name"}
                    id={"name"}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-4">
                <div className="">
                  <Inputs
                    label={"Account Number"}
                    type={"number"}
                    name={"account"}
                    id={"account"}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-4">
                <div className="">
                  <Inputs
                    label={"Bank Name"}
                    type={"text"}
                    name={"bank"}
                    id={"bank"}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="">
                  <Inputs
                    label={"Amount"}
                    type={"number"}
                    name={"amount"}
                    id={"amount"}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-4">
                <Button
                  outline={false}
                  text={"Proceed"}
                  styles={"text-center"}
                />
              </div>
            </Form>
          </Formik>
        </SpringModal>
        
        

      </div>
    </StyledWithdraw>
  );
};

export default Witdraw;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly do you mean with *filling a form it just goes blank*? If you're submitting it or if you're filling it out? In general, you can have as many forms as you'd like in your app but (without any modifications) only one of them get's submitted at a time

Comment: Hi sir, yes the form goes blank when i try filling it

Comment: This is the error i get sir......react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Cannot update a component (`ForwardRef(ModalUnstyled)`) while rendering a different component (`ForwardRef(Fade)`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `ForwardRef(Fade)`,

Comment: utils.ts:126 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'phone')
    at setIn (utils.ts:126:1)
    at formikReducer (Formik.tsx:79:1)
    at updateReducer (react-dom.development.js:16664:1)
    at Object.useReducer (react-dom.development.js:17898:1)
    at useReducer (react.development.js:1626:1)
    at useFormik (Formik.tsx:173:1)
    at Formik (Formik.tsx:992:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork

Comment: Well, could you paste a reproducible example without all your images and stuff? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . It seems your error is in `Formik.tsx` reading a variable that is - at time of access - undefined.

Comment: Yes sir i just did that sir, i have edited the react code to be simplier

Comment: I think this is where the issue is from in the Formik.tsx page.. Any idea on how i can manipulate this?     handleSubmit: (e?: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> | undefined) => void;